# How to get Spring mvc validation messages without using messages.properties?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, validation

I have a Spring mvc application with a Controller, Model, Service, and Validation classes.  Everything works fine.  In developing what I currently have, I stored the validation messages in a messages.properties file -which I registered in a configuration class like this:

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {

    final ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("[package name]/messages/messages");

    return messageSource;
}
```

In the Validator, I add a validation message if the user didn't answer a field such as this:

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "age", "required", new Object[] {"Age"});
```

In the messages.properties file I have this (above 'age' is the name of the model object, 'required' is the key used to retrieve the message in the messages.properties file):

```
required = {0} is required.
```

Ok, again -this all works fine.  But what I'd like to do is externalize the messages to a database (basically, these are corporate messages that all applications use).

My question is -how do I get Spring to use the database instead of messages.properties?  Or is I do use messages.properties, to only store the message's id (database key) instead of the message itself?

I have a couple ideas of what to do -but no idea how to do either one.  I 'think' that the Spring-form tag library ends up performing the work of getting the actual message.  Perhaps I could somehow intercept that call?  Or maybe somehow change the messageSource to something else rather than defining the messages.properties file.

Anyways, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a ResourceBundleMessageSource use a custom MessageSource implementation, which back in a DB. Unfortunately Spring itself doesn't have such an implementation, as described in the jira issue:  https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-364

But implementing the MessageSource Interface is straightforward, you can even see a sample implementation attached to the jira issue: https://jira.springsource.org/secure/attachment/10261/JdbcMessageSource.java

Answer (score 1):

You can try `Errors.rejectValue(String field, String errorCode, String defaultMessage)` method. I too had the same problem. In my case I used `...errors.rejectValue("firstName", "error.firstName", "plz enter ur first name!!.");`

This should ideally use the `defaultMessage` in the scenario where it can't find the error code from message source.